# Делать ссылки кликабельными в тексте

Tags: c#, wpf

Использую `ListView` для отображения логов.
Иногда в логе бывают ссылки (напимер, "Некорректная ссылка: http://example.com/"), хотелось бы, чтобы на них просто нажать можно было и они открылись в обычном браузере.

Можно ли это сделать автоматически или придётся парсить ручками и конвертировать в комбинацию `Run` и `Hyperlink`?

Comment: Ручками. Хуже того, корректная регулярка для адреса — это тот ещё головняк, гуглятся обычно частичные полуправильные решения.

Comment: @VladD, а у какого нибудь DevExpress или Telerik нет решений? Я где то точно видел, как просто вставленный текст превращался в кликабельный. Найти не могу, вот и задаю вопрос.

Comment: Я не знаю, если честно, ну и я бы не доверял чужим разборщикам текста.

Comment: @VladD парсить рандомный текст хотя бы в простую модель "текст с вставками ссылок" - тоже не хочется. Готовое решение было бы приятнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя реализацию [отсюда](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/625509/WPF-TextBlock-with-highlighted-and-interactive-lin) и regex [отсюда](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) (правда, я добавил в свой шаблон запятые, как разделитель, в логах так встречается, к сожалению) получилась вот такая реализация.

```
  public class TextBlockWithHyperlinks : TextBlock
  {
    private static readonly Regex HyperlinkRegex = new Regex(@"(https?|ftp):\/\/[^\s/$.?#].[^\s,]*");

    static TextBlockWithHyperlinks()
    {
      DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBlockWithHyperlinks), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextBlockWithHyperlinks)));
    }

    public TextBlockWithHyperlinks()
    {
      TargetUpdated += (s, args) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, new Action(ParseHyperlinks));
    }

    private void ParseHyperlinks()
    {
      var style = HyperlinkStyle;
      var text = Text;
      var matches = HyperlinkRegex.Matches(text);
      if (matches.Count == 0)
        return;

      Inlines.Clear();
      var lastIndex = 0;
      foreach (Match match in matches)
      {
        Inlines.Add(text.Substring(lastIndex, match.Index - lastIndex));
        lastIndex = match.Index + match.Length;
        var run = new Run(match.Value) { Style = style };
        run.MouseDown += RunOnMouseDown;
        Inlines.Add(run);
      }
      Inlines.Add(text.Substring(lastIndex));
    }

    private void RunOnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
    {
      var run = sender as Run;
      if (run == null)
        return;

      OnHyperlinkPressed(new HyperlinkPressedEventArgs(run.Text));
    }

    public event EventHandler<HyperlinkPressedEventArgs> HyperlinkPressed;

    public void OnHyperlinkPressed(HyperlinkPressedEventArgs args)
    {
      var handler = HyperlinkPressed;
      handler?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HyperlinkStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HyperlinkStyle",
                                                                                              typeof(Style),
                                                                                              typeof(TextBlockWithHyperlinks));

    public Style HyperlinkStyle
    {
      get { return (Style)GetValue(HyperlinkStyleProperty); }
      set { SetValue(HyperlinkStyleProperty, value); }
    }
  }

  public class HyperlinkPressedEventArgs : EventArgs
  {
    public readonly Uri Hyperlink;

    public HyperlinkPressedEventArgs(Uri hyperlink)
    {
      Hyperlink = hyperlink;
    }

    public HyperlinkPressedEventArgs(string hyperlink) : this(new Uri(hyperlink))
    {
    }
  }
```

В разметку вставляется легко, есть только одно но - всегда надо включать `NotifyOnTargetUpdated`.

```
          <local:TextBlockWithHyperlinks HyperlinkPressed="TextBlockWithLinks_OnHyperlinkPressed" 
                                    HyperlinkStyle="{StaticResource HyperlinkStyle}"
                                    Text="{Binding FormattedMessage, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
```

Стиль простой, подчеркивание и синий цвет:

```
<Style x:Key="HyperlinkStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Run}" >
  <Style.Setters>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
  </Style.Setters>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline"/>
      <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Обработчик ссылок по идее надо бы делать с защитой от опасных операций, но пока так:

```
private void TextBlockWithLinks_OnHyperlinkPressed(object sender, HyperlinkPressedEventArgs args)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(args.Hyperlink.OriginalString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если ссылки могут встречаться в любом  месте лога, то можно написать регулярное выражение, которое вытащит нужную ссылку или ссылки. Сформировать на основе полученной информации модель представления. А потом написать шаблон для элемента ListView, который будет использовать HyperLink.

Comment: Слушайте, я практически это и написал в вопросе. Я ищу готовые решения, чтобы не изобретать велосипед.

Comment: @Monk Может быть подойдёт что-то вроде этого https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/625509/WPF-TextBlock-with-highlighted-and-interactive-lin?

Comment: На костылях и приходится поправлять, но сойдет.