# Как сделать ссылку на email рабочей (windows phone 8.1)?

Tags: c#, xaml, email, windows-phone-8.1

Я вывожу в TextBlock адрес электронной почты. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на него открывалось окно создания нового письма?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/660472/196257 - только поменять regex на email-ы и при клике не просто запускать обработку ссылки, а добавить `mailto:`

Comment: Не уверен правда, работает ли оно на винфонах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте в обработчике клика (или в команде) следующий код:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(@"mailto:test@test.ru?subject=Тема письма"));
```